# Hidden folders in home directory

Tags: macos

Launching a simple `ls -a` from Terminal in my home directory I found out that there are a couple of hidden folders I was not aware of: `.cups` and `.jssc`.

I don't really know what those things are and I don't like them to be in my home folder. Anyone knows what are these related to (and maybe what program usually create them) and whether it is safe to remove them?

I'm using Mac OS 10.8.5 if it can be useful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`.cups` is used by [Common Unix Printing System](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CUPS), as the name insinuates, this is used by the printing system.

I believe that the `.jssc` is created by the java simple serial connector library. My bet is you have some java application that uses this library. I wouldn't worry about it.